# How to upgrade `pip3.8` for `python-3.8.2`? I have two python versions`(python-3.6 and python-3.8.2)` and two `pip`s (`pip3 and pip3.8`) respectively

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Whenever I upgrade the `pip` the `python-3.6` version gets upgraded and when I do same for `pip3.8` I get errors. Following snippets shows the detail:

`users@user01:/mnt/d/codes/py38$ pip3.8 install --upgrade pip3.8`

`Collecting pip3.8`

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3.8 (from versions: none)`
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip3.8`

**Here's the system prompts:**

`WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

And when I run `pip3.8 --versioin` the following pops up:

`pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

*Need Help!!*

*Thank You!!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo pip3.8 install --upgrade pip
```

will give you the permissions you need.

If you aren't an administrator on the machine, you either need to `su` to one, or get them to run the command for you.

Comment: and for windows users, running cmd as administrator will do it.